# how to append onClick event in jquery

Tags: jquery

In a pre tag, I want to put some html (span and onclick) but I think the syntax is not correct. How can I make this work correct?

```
$('pre', this).append('<span onClick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, 'select1')">Select All</span>');
```

Comment: Your code is missing `+` concatenations around your strings and variables. `$('pre', this).append('<span onClick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, ' + select1 + ')">Select All</span>');`

Comment: $('#pr').append('<span onClick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, select1)">Select All</span>');      ''pr'' is  id of span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    var span = $('<span>SelectAll</span>');
span.click(function(){
  fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, 'select1');
});
$('pre', this).append(span);
```